# Why doesn't the Firefox tab audio icon always show for noisy tabs?

Tags: firefox, audio

Firefox now shows an audio icon for tabs which play sound, [it works on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

[image]

But not on all noisy pages, for example there is no speaker icon on the tab for [this page](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/09/07/politics/hillary-clinton-donald-trump-presidential-forum/index.html).

Why does it work for some pages but not others?

Comment: have you got any examples of pages that dont work?

Comment: Yes, there's a link in the original question.